# Swift: try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url) exits without throwing and without result if endpoint is down

Tags: swift, urlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have a .NET core WebApi endpoint with a PING method that simply returns "PONG" when called.
In a SwiftUI app (XCode 15 with iOS 17.2 target) I use this code for calling it:

```
func ping () async throws -> String {
        
        let call = "\(baseURL)/Ping"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: call) else {
            throw SmartReaderError.invalidURL
        }
        
        do {
            
            let (jsonData, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let responseString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            
            if responseString == "PONG" {
                return responseString! as String
            }
            else {
                return "KO"
            }
        } catch {
            return "KO"
        }
    }
```

For testing purposes I just kept the endpoint down. The call to `URLSession.shared.data...` doesn't return a value nor throws an error. It just makes func ping () exiting and the `let responseString...` is never reached. Even setting a breakpoint didn't clarified...

I expected that, if the http endpoint is unreachable or doesn't respond at least an error was thrown.

Comment: "doesn't return a value nor throws an error. It just makes func ping () exiting and the `let responseString...` is never reached." That is not possible. Please show a [mcve]. Is there any public URLs that you can reproduce this with?

Comment: You are ignoring the response code, check that

Comment: Unrelated by why are you using `NSString`? Just use `let responseString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)`.

Comment: You can try with any unreachable address... The purpose is to ping an unresponsive address and handle the situation properly. I just realized that, indeed, an exception is caught after 60 seconds from the call. I just didn't take the time to wait. Reducing call timeout, however, doesn't seem to work. I tried something like: URLSession.shared.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 1

Answer (score -1):

The issue was solved reducing  URLSession.defaultConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest value for pinging purposes.